# attempting to decipher a cgminer share.log

Tags: hash, cgminer, logging

Here is 1 entry from a share processed in a feathercoin mine pool:

```
1367788723,accept,ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff070000,http://mining-foreman.org:11341,GPU1,1,b8641194d4b41e5dbc3fb6c68477f4754e01c6ef9b6f37a84d18807cd8060000,00000001579070dc02677a4a1a5f5cbe4bec71d2788472bf5d246f341124c04e9177b2ebc8b00d25c4c8245a44c6410eba2e122101ea1e4e1b1475ebebb8c0b25f3b74ec5186ccb21c0217a29b665700000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080020000
```

The cgminer readme describes the format as thus:
 *timestamp,disposition,target,pool,dev,thr,sharehash,sharedata*

Now as I understand it, there is a difficulty reported on the cgminer screen of 8.02M. A share that solves for higher than that qualifies as successful mine.

- Question 1: How is that 8.02M number arrived at (current network difficulty 122.35060749)?
- Q2: using the above data, how can I see what I *did* solve for?

Comment: You're making an assumption that your interpretation of 8.02M is even correct...? I can't make sense of share.log - have you looked at the source code? That might help you understand how the log is created.